# .NET Core 3.1 gRPC Docker: Could not make proto path relative

Tags: c#, visual-studio, docker, .net-core, grpc

**Problem description**

Publishing a default .NET Core 3.1 gRPC service (generated by Visual Studio Community 2019 16.5.4) via Docker fails due to `Could not make proto path relative : error : Protos/GreeterService.proto: No such file or directory [/src/ProjectName/ProjectName.csproj]`.

**How to reproduce**

1. Create a new gRPC Project with .net Core 3.1 and Docker support (Linux)
2. Open the generated Dockerfile
3. Remove the directory from the copy path of the first `COPY` (this is an error in the default Dockerfile):

   `COPY ["ProjectName/ProjectName.csproj", "ProjectName/"]` => `COPY ["ProjectName.csproj", "ProjectName/"]`
4. Run `docker build .`

Now the line `RUN dotnet build "ProjectName.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build` throws an error:

```
Protos : warning : directory does not exist. [/src/ProjectName/ProjectName.csproj]
Could not make proto path relative : error : Protos/GreeterService.proto: No such file or directory [/src/ProjectName/ProjectName.csproj]
```

But if you go into the container, the file actually exists at exactly this location:

```
root@1b49365bc690:/src/ProjectName# ls
ProjectName.csproj  obj
```

**What I tried**

I couldn't find much regarding this issue, therefore the only helpful seeming answer I found was [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59746779/4244096) which recommends to add `ProtoRoot="Protos"` within the .csproj file, but sadly this didn't help.

Furthermore I tried to manually execute the `dotnet build` command from different working directories with various target path combinations but none worked. The verbose flag also didn't provide any useful information:

```
    Task "ProtoCompile"
      /root/.nuget/packages/grpc.tools/2.27.0/tools/linux_x64/protoc --csharp_out=obj/Release/netcoreapp3.1 --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=/root/.nuget/packages/grpc.tools/2.27.0/tools/linux_x64/grpc_csharp_plugin --grpc_out=obj/Release/netcoreapp3.1 --grpc_opt=no_client --proto_path=/root/.nuget/packages/grpc.tools/2.27.0/build/native/include --proto_path=Protos --dependency_out=obj/Release/netcoreapp3.1/1255d1a520d30ea4_greet.protodep --error_format=msvs Protos/greet.proto
1:7>Protos : warning : directory does not exist. [/src/ProjectName/ProjectName.csproj]
1:7>Could not make proto path relative : error : Protos/greet.proto: No such file or directory [/src/ProjectName/ProjectName.csproj]
```

I hope someone can help me out with this problem; thank you in advance.

**Ressources**

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ProjectName.csproj", "ProjectName/"]
RUN dotnet restore "ProjectName/ProjectName.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/ProjectName"
RUN dotnet build "ProjectName.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ProjectName.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ProjectName.dll"]
```

greet.proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "ProjectName";

package greet;

// The greeting service definition.
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply);
}

// The request message containing the user's name.
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

// The response message containing the greetings.
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>secretsId</UserSecretsId>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Protobuf Include="Protos\greet.proto" GrpcServices="Server" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Grpc.AspNetCore" Version="2.27.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.10.8" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: I had the same error but it turns out I was too aggressively tuning my .dockerignore file and I'd inadvertently added the protos folder path...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it to work by changing the Dockerfile to following:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY "ProjectName.csproj" .
RUN dotnet restore "ProjectName.csproj"
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "ProjectName.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ProjectName.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ProjectName.dll"]
```

I'm not 100% sure why this works, but I guess that it has something to do with how the gRPC compiler discovers which files it has to compile.

Answer (score 11):

Adding a comment here as I had the same Error message but for a different reason. In my case, I was on Windows building a Linux docker image.

In my csproj, the Proto was included as "Protos\MyService.proto" - turns out on the filesystem the filename was Myservice.proto (lowercase 's') - obviously the Linux build container is case sensitive, hence; "No such file or directory"!

Easy fix but took me about an hour of head scratching