# protoc error validator.proto: File not found

Tags: go, import, protocol-buffers, protoc

I am getting .proto File not found error in below command

**Command**

```
protoc -I/usr/local/include -I. \
        -I/home/xxUserxx/go/pkg/mod/github.com/mwitkow/go-proto-validators@v0.3.0/ \
        -I/home/xxUserxx/go/src \
        -I/home/xxUserxx/go/pkg/mod/github.com/xxOrgxx/xxPrivateRepoxx@v1.2.2/proto \
        -I/home/xxUserxx/go/pkg/mod/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway@v1.9.2/third_party/googleapis \
        --grpc-gateway_out=logtostderr=true,allow_repeated_fields_in_body=true:./proto \
        --swagger_out=logtostderr=true,allow_repeated_fields_in_body=true:./proto \
        --govalidators_out=./proto --go_out=plugins=grpc:./proto \
        test1.proto test2.proto
```

**Output**:
Below error is failing protoc.

```
github.com/mwitkow/go-proto-validators/validator.proto: File not found.
test1.proto:7:1: Import "github.com/mwitkow/go-proto-validators/validator.proto" was not found or had errors.
```

**Edit1:** Below is the test1.proto file as requested. Here line number 7 has validator.proto import

```
syntax = "proto3";

package proto;
option go_package = "proto";

import "google/api/annotations.proto";
import "github.com/mwitkow/go-proto-validators/validator.proto";

service TestService {
    rpc GetTests(GetTestsRequest) returns (GetTestsResponse) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      get: "/test"
    };
  } 
}

message GetTestsRequest {
}

message GetTestsResponse {
    repeated Test tests = 1;
}

message Test {
  int64 id = 1;
  string name = 2;
  string description = 3;
  int64 externalId = 4;
  int64 providerId = 5;
  bool isArchived = 6;
}
```

Comment: Please post minimal reproducible example including relevant parts of `test1.proto` file.

Answer (score 0):

As this *[comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21134066/error-using-import-in-proto-file/21152266#comment48808718_21152266)* suggests, use the **Top Level Source Directory** that is shared between your proto project and the one that you're trying to reference.

*[Here's another example.](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/issues/1453#issuecomment-382414672)*