# ERROR when trying to compile protoc files: file not found or had errors

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, protoc

I am trying to compile protoc files using this command:

```
protoc/bin/protoc models/research/object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
```

but I am getting  this output on cmd

```
object_detection/protos/flexible_grid_anchor_generator.proto: File not found.
object_detection/protos/grid_anchor_generator.proto: File not found.
object_detection/protos/multiscale_anchor_generator.proto: File not found.
object_detection/protos/ssd_anchor_generator.proto: File not found.
models/research/object_detection/protos/anchor_generator.proto:5:1: Import "object_detection/protos/flexible_grid_anchor_generator.proto" was not found or had errors.
models/research/object_detection/protos/anchor_generator.proto:6:1: Import "object_detection/protos/grid_anchor_generator.proto" was not found or had errors.
models/research/object_detection/protos/anchor_generator.proto:7:1: Import "object_detection/protos/multiscale_anchor_generator.proto" was not found or had errors.
models/research/object_detection/protos/anchor_generator.proto:8:1: Import "object_detection/protos/ssd_anchor_generator.proto" was not found or had errors.
models/research/object_detection/protos/anchor_generator.proto:14:5: "GridAnchorGenerator" is not defined.
models/research/object_detection/protos/anchor_generator.proto:15:5: "SsdAnchorGenerator" is not defined.
models/research/object_detection/protos/anchor_generator.proto:16:5: "MultiscaleAnchorGenerator" is not defined.
models/research/object_detection/protos/anchor_generator.proto:17:5: "FlexibleGridAnchorGenerator" is not defined.
```

So what can be the problem
Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to run the protobuf compiler in the correct directory. In that case, it would be `models/research`:

```sh
$ cd models/research
$ ../../protoc/bin/protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
```

The protobuf files will be compiled to python. In the directory `object_detection/protos/`, you should have python files named after the protobuf file (i.e `<name_protobuf>_pb2.py`).

There is relative imports in those protobuf files, so it's important that the protobuf compiler is run in the correct directory. You have a hint that it might be the error as the `File not Found` error message lists a different path than your current directory.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I tried this and no error showed, in fact nothing showed up, is that normal? can I consider the files compiled? @lescurel

Comment: This answer helped me and nothing showed up afterwards @Jenny 

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue recently. I cleared it by changing the file paths in the proto file.

For example, a proto file had following imports.

```
import "object_detection/protos/flexible_grid_anchor_generator.proto";
import "object_detection/protos/grid_anchor_generator.proto";
import "object_detection/protos/multiscale_anchor_generator.proto";
import "object_detection/protos/ssd_anchor_generator.proto";
```

I changed it to the following.

```
import "flexible_grid_anchor_generator.proto";
import "grid_anchor_generator.proto";
import "multiscale_anchor_generator.proto";
import "ssd_anchor_generator.proto";
```

The reason is all the proto files are present in the same object_detection/protos folder so path is not required.

I changed the references in all the proto files and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

On my side, I followed Harish recommendation above to remove the file path. Then compiled the proto files one by one then added the `--proto_path=path/to/imports` flag for each file.
Find this https://stackoverflow.com/a/21152266/12001817 that when you compile a .proto file that includes imports, you must provide the paths to the imported files so that the compiler can find them. For example, you might use a command like the following to compile a .proto file that imports other files:

Sample command which have worked:

`$protoc/bin/protoc --proto_path=models/research/object_detection/protos models/research/object_detection/protos/box_predictor.proto --python_out=.`